# Jquery function order to get variable for insert into local database

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I have an issue where I am submitting a form via Jquery into a local database. However, based upon one of the input fields, I am going to an ajax call to get the matching picture file name. When I click Submit, the scripts run, but the function to the ajax runs after the data has been put into the database table ( I see the alert fire after the form data has been entered). Therefore, I am not able to put the image name in when the form is submitted. Can you help me understand how to make the ajax function call to get the value for newpic before the SQL function runs?

My sample code is noted below, with secure details removed. Thanks for any help.

```
$("#submit_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodID = $("#i_admin_prodID").val();
            var userID = $("#i_admin_uid").val();
    var drawSize = $("#i_admin_dSize").val();
    var pocket = $("#i_admin_pocket").val();
    var orgItemID = $("#i_admin_orgItemID").val();
    var itemID = $("#admin_item_id").val();
    if ( itemID ) {
     newpic = getPicture(itemID);
    }
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO vend_products ...")
      }, function(error) {
        alert("error" + error.message);
      }, function() {
        sendOrdertoEmail();
    });
}); 


function getPicture(zItemID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : '/get_new_picture.php?IT=' + zItemID,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('PIC: ' + data );
        return data;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is due to Ajax which works asynchronously.

I don't know if you want the request to return anything to you. I let you modify for your project

Try like this :

```
$("#submit_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var prodID = $("#i_admin_prodID").val();
            var userID = $("#i_admin_uid").val();
    var drawSize = $("#i_admin_dSize").val();
    var pocket = $("#i_admin_pocket").val();
    var orgItemID = $("#i_admin_orgItemID").val();
    var itemID = $("#admin_item_id").val();
    if ( itemID ) {
     getPicture(itemID);
    }
}); 

function getPicture(zItemID) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : '/get_new_picture.php?IT=' + zItemID,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('PIC: ' + data );
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
  }).done(function(data) { //data is for your newPic
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
          tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO vend_products ...")
        }, function(error) {
          alert("error" + error.message);
        }, function() {
          sendOrdertoEmail();
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for idea and clarification of how Ajax works. While this is not ideal, as I have other forms that need to use the getPicture function and insert into different tables, I maybe able to use your idea and duplicate the SQL function based upon which form was submitted.

Comment: @glatin `$.ajax` also returns a `Promise`, so you should be able to use it synchronously with `async/await`